# Name for point in space which is contained in all nonempty open sets?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, terminology

Suppose $(X, \mathfrak{T})$ is a topological space. Let $x \in X$ have the property that

$$\forall \, \, \mathrm{open} \, \, \varnothing \neq U \subseteq X, x \in U$$

In other words, $x \in \displaystyle\bigcap_{\varnothing \neq U \in \mathfrak{T}} U$, i.e. $x$ is contained in the intersection of all open sets of $X$. I haven't found anything online about a name for such a point. It might be of little interest as this point is particularly problematic in separability and may only show up in low-level separability-axiom spaces. **Is there a name for a point (or for a collection of points) like this?** Am I confusing this for an accumulation point?

Comment: Mostly occurs in the Zariski topology from algebraic geometry. It is called a generic point.

Comment: There is no such point, because the empty set is open.

Comment: @user14111 Thank you for raising this issue. Maybe I should have been more clear in stipulating that $U$ is nonempty.

Comment: Note that the equivalent condition is: $\overline{\{x\}}=X$. And so *dense point* seems very natural.

Answer (score 2):

Such a point is usually called a *dense point*, since $\{x\}$ is a dense subset.

The related term *generic point* is used in algebraic geometry (as mentioned by @orangeskid) even when there is not an actual point that is in every open set, so to be unambiguous I would stick to *dense point*.